# Task Completion Notification Emails to specific profile level

Tags: apex, trigger

How to prevent the task Completion Notification Emails to specific profile level.Means we want send a task email to particular profile level Like **`IdentifyUser`**,**`Marketing`**, **`Sales`**.

For that we have written one trigger but that trigger sending mail to all profile level.

Can any one please help us how to restrict the specific profile level.

Here is my bit of trigger code.

```
trigger EmailNotification on Task(before update) {
        if (userinfo.getProfileId() != '00e28000000sea7AAA') {
            Set < Id > ownerIds = new Set < Id > ();
            for (Task tsk: Trigger.New) {
                if (tsk.Status == 'Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
                    ownerIds.add(tsk.CreatedById);
                    System.debug('CreatedByID' + tsk.Id);
                }
            }
            Map < Id, User > userMap = new Map < Id, User > ([select Name, Email from User where Id in: ownerIds]);
            List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > emailMsglist = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
            for (Task tsk: Trigger.New) {
                if (tsk.Status == 'Completed' && Trigger.oldMap.get(tsk.Id).Status != 'Completed' && tsk.OwnerId != tsk.CreatedById) {
                    User theUser = userMap.get(tsk.CreatedById);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to send this E-Mail from Apex? You can use a workflow rule + email notification for this

Comment: Hard-coded ids...

Comment: Hi,  Through trigger we can sending task emails. is there any possible to restrict specific profile level through trigger based on the above code?